# Is the map service support multi language?

Tags: geolocation, mapping, geo

we found problem using map service, which we cannot obtain location when user doing attendance in different country such as japan (that have different alphabet). fyi, I am in Indonesia

We would like to use geo tagging to capture user location while doing attendance. is it support multi language ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused about what kind of data you retrieve using the maps service!

full name of the address or coordinates?

For the case of users who are in different countries and languages, you can just take the geocoding data

Later this data can be converted into a complete address, assuming you use the Google Maps service, you can do this [geocoding reverse](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)